# Why does using arguments make this function so much slower?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, math

I have recently been working on creating a prime-number finding program. However, **I came to notice that one function was much slower when it used arguments than when it used pre-set values**.

Across 3 different versions, it becomes clear that the variables are significantly slowing down the program, and I would like to know why.

## *Version 1*: 7.5 seconds

Here was the original (somewhat simplified for this question) function:

```
def version1(n, p):
  return ((n*n - 2) & ((1 << p) - 1)) + ((n*n - 2) >> p)
```

When ran with the `timeit` module 100 times:

```
timeit.timeit("version1(200, 500000000)", "from __main__ import version1", number=100)
```

it takes `7.5` seconds.

## *Version 2*: 0.0001 seconds

However, here is the second version, in which there are no parameters, and the numbers are directly placed in the return value. The equasion is exactly the same as *Version 1*:

```
def version2():
  return ((200*200 - 2) & ((1 << 500000000) - 1)) + ((200*200 - 2) >> 500000000)
```

When ran with the `timeit` module 100 times:

```
timeit.timeit("version2()", "from __main__ import version2", number=100
```

in this only takes `0.00001` seconds!

## *Version 3*: 6.3 seconds

Lastly, for completeness, I tried a version that had no parameters, but still kept its values as variables:

```
def version3():
  n = 200
  p = 500000000
  return ((n*n - 2) & ((1 << p) - 1)) + ((n*n - 2) >> p)
```

When ran with `timeit`:

```
timeit.timeit("version3()", "from __main__ import version3", number = 100)
```

it took `6.3` seconds, which is relatively close to *Version 1*.

**Why is it that the same function can take so much longer when there are variables involved, and how can I make *Version 1* more effient?**

Comment: Constant expressions are optimized by Python's peephole optimizer immediately after compilation. `version2` simply returns the constant `39998`.

Comment: Version 2 is faster than varsion 1 because there are no variable. This means that the entire expression can be calculated ahead of time. This means that `((200*200 - 2) & ((1 << 500000000) - 1)) + ((200*200 - 2) >> 500000000)` will be replaced with a single number even before the function is called.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Python pre-computes calculations when compiling as a so-called [*peep-hole optimisation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def version2():
...   return ((200*200 - 2) & ((1 << 500000000) - 1)) + ((200*200 - 2) >> 500000000)
...
>>> dis.dis(version2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST              13 (39998)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

`version2()` returns the already-calculated value, and does **no actual work**. Returning a constant is of course much, much faster than having to calculate the value each time.

See the [`fold_binops_on_constants` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Python/peephole.c#L221-L318) in the `peephole.c` Python source file for the details on how the compiler does this.

As a result, compiling `version2` takes (a lot) more time than `version1`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> version1_text = '''\
... def version1(n, p):
...   return ((n*n - 2) & ((1 << p) - 1)) + ((n*n - 2) >> p)
... '''
>>> version2_text = '''\
... def version2():
...   return ((200*200 - 2) & ((1 << 500000000) - 1)) + ((200*200 - 2) >> 500000000)
... '''
>>> timeit.timeit("compile(t, '', 'exec')", 'from __main__ import version1_text as t', number=10)
0.00028649598243646324
>>> timeit.timeit("compile(t, '', 'exec')", 'from __main__ import version2_text as t', number=10)
2.2103765579813626
```

Good thing Python caches the bytecode results of compilation!

The intermediary results of each sub-expression is also stored in the `co_consts` attribute of the code object, and some of those are rather large:

```
>>> import sys
>>> consts = version2.__code__.co_consts
>>> for obj in consts:
...     size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
...     print(f'{type(obj)!s:<18} {size:<8} {"<too large to print>" if size > 100 else obj}')
...
<class 'NoneType'> 16       None
<class 'int'>      28       200
<class 'int'>      28       2
<class 'int'>      28       1
<class 'int'>      28       500000000
<class 'int'>      28       40000
<class 'int'>      28       39998
<class 'int'>      66666692 <too large to print>
<class 'int'>      66666692 <too large to print>
<class 'int'>      28       39998
<class 'int'>      28       40000
<class 'int'>      28       39998
<class 'int'>      24       0
<class 'int'>      28       39998
```

so this did make the bytecode cache a little larger:

```
>>> import marshal
>>> len(marshal.dumps(version1.__code__))
129
>>> len(marshal.dumps(version2.__code__))
133333481
```

That's a minimum of 127MB for the `.pyc` file for the module that contains your non-argument version!

Comment: I've filed http://bugs.python.org/issue30293 to see if the optimizer should avoid creating such large folding results.

Answer (score 4):

As Martijn's in-depth answer points out, `version2` is the faster one of all due to constant folding CPython performs, the number of variables doesn't come into play.

As for `version3` versus `version1`, `version3` is faster because there's additional argument parsing performed when calling `version1`.

Python needs to perform this parsing for every invocation. When you time it and repeat the invocation 100 times, this difference (that's otherwise not really noticeable) shows. You'd get *slightly* different timing results if you defined the arguments as `**kwargs`, `*args` or with a default value.